# Installing executable with linked libraries on other system (GCC)

Tags: macos, gcc, linker

I have an application which use some libraries on OS X and they are licensed by LGPL. I can link them statically or dynamically. Everything is working fine. But what should i do if i want to install my application on another computer with OS X? I mean, on another system there will not be those libraries already installed and application probably will not run. I should to place this libs somewhere (as i understand in the same directory with binary), where user can change it by another version (due to LGPL), but i don't understand how should i do it right. Can someone explain this techinque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had to face this myself recently, I advise you to start off immidiately by understanding how [bundles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html) work and making use of them (specifically, [application bundles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13)). Moreover you will have to understand how tools like [install_name_tool](http://qin.laya.com/tech_coding_help/dylib_linking.html) works. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, it was quite informative. Is there the same technique in Linux and Windows (MINGW) ?

Comment: For Windows you will most probably end up creating your own folder under %Program Files%\CompanyName\ProductName\ where executables will go, while all dynamic libraries will go under %Winsysdir%. Under Linux, I personally prefer the FHS standard and you can read a nice article here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4121. Best of luck!